# SQLite delete a specific row java swing

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

I'm trying to delete a specific row from a table, and I can't find the way to do it.

I was following https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/rrmbsKyKRCE but it didn't work.

my query is:

```
        String query = "delete from " + type + " where name=? and score =? (SELECT score FROM " + type + " ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1)";
        pst.setString(1, tempName); 
        pst.setInt(2, tempScore);
```

The string "type" is the table name (no bugs with the table name) and in the table I have to rows: name and score. and pst is the prepared statement.

The error I get: "[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)".

I've noticed that the link above is for android, but I couldn't find something for java swing...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for an `IN` clause

```
String query = "delete from " + type + " where name=? and score IN (SELECT score FROM " + type + " ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1)";
```

Comment: So simple. I don't get the run-time error now, but it doesn't delete any row... needless to say that "delete from " + type + " where name=? and score=?"; deletes ALL the entries, instead of one...